# Can Cumber transform into a super saiyan in the anime?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-heroes

Someone pointed in Youtube that Cumber might be unable to transform into a super saiyan. Is this so? We see he transform in Oozaru, an orange Oozaru many including myself have assumed to be the golden oozaru (saiyan + oozaru transformation) but he never transforms first into a super saiyan for later turning into an oozaru, and whe he turns back to human form after Fu made the artificial moon disappear, he doesnt retain his supposed super saiyan transformation. Could it be that his oozaru form is not the golden oozaru form but the regular oozaru form and that he can't transform into a supersaiyan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the Orange Great Ape form but in the fifth episode which is the most recent he was able to transform into Super Saiyan Three before he fought against Super Saiyan 4 Vegito, so he at least has SS1 and SS2.